# Can I use glyphicons as collapsible bullet points?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

Is it possible to set clickable glyphicons for bullet points instead of buttons? Right now I've managed to put buttons, but I'm hiding the bullet points.

Code is here:
http://www.codeply.com/go/WDCzrCNhYG

I'm trying to put glyphicons for bullets, so that when I click on them they collapse if they're bolded (meaning there's description in the sub-bullets) and that they're normal or faded when they're not collapsible.

Something like this:
http://www.codeply.com/go/zAVFMMybdr
but with Item3 and Item4 bullets to be bolded and clickable/collapsible.

Right now I'm trying to figure out if I can use buttons and hide the background and the outline so only the glyphicon is shown. But in that case I would also need to specify that Item1 and Item2 buttons are not clickable.

Any help is much appreciated. I'm new to this so I'm sorry if I didn't explain myself well enough:)

P.S. As instructed I'm adding the code here instead of providing an outside link.

```css
.btn {
    padding: 0px 5px;
}

/* Icon when the collapsible content is shown */
  .btn:after {
    font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
    content: "\e113";
    float: left;
  }

  /* Icon when the collapsible content is hidden */
  .btn.collapsed:after {
    content: "\e080";
  }
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<body>
<p class="font_heading"><small>Attractions</small></p>
                            <ul id="placePul" style="list-style: none;">
                                <li style="margin-left:28px">Item1</li>   
                                <li style="margin-left:28px">Item2</li>
                                <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Demo1"></button> Item3</li>
                                    <ul id="Demo1" class="collapse">
                                        <li>Description 1</li>
                                        <li>Description 2</li>
                                        <li>Description 3</li>
                                    </ul>
                                <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Demo2"></button> Item4</li>
                                    <ul id="Demo2" class="collapse">
                                        <li>Description 4</li>
                                        <li>Description 5</li>
                                        <li>Description 6</li>
                                    </ul>
           </ul>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It certainly is...you just have to move the `data-toggle` attribute to the `li` and then target that specifically.

```css
li {
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  position: relative;
}
/* Icon when the collapsible content is shown */

li[data-toggle="collapse"]:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
  content: "\e113";
  color:black;
}
/* Icon when the collapsible content is hidden */

li[data-toggle="collapse"].collapsed:after {
  content: "\e080";
  color:grey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<h4>Toggling </h4>
<ul id="placePul" style="list-style: none;">
  <li>Item1</li>
  <li>Item2</li>
  <li class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Demo1">Item3</li>
  <ul id="Demo1" class="collapse">
    <li>Description 1</li>
    <li>Description 2</li>
    <li>Description 3</li>
  </ul>
  <li class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Demo2">Item4</li>
  <ul id="Demo2" class="collapse">
    <li>Description 4</li>
    <li>Description 5</li>
    <li>Description 6</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! Thanks:)